# Obtener indice de un array asociativo desde consulta sql

Tags: php, sql

tengo la siguiente función que recupera un array de una consulta sql, y quiero mostrar el indice (nombre, apellidos,...) del array asociativo he utilizado la función key y array_keys, y no lo logro extraerlos.

Os dejo la función, gracias:

```
function comprobarDatos($pdo)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT nombre, apellidos, dni, direccion, telefono from usuarios where login=:login';

    $gsent = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $login = [$_SESSION['login']];
    $gsent->execute($login);

    $resultadoDatos = $gsent->fetchAll();
   // var_dump($resultadoDatos);
    foreach($resultadoDatos as $filas){
        for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 

            ?> <h6> <ul> <li> <?= key($resultadoDatos[$i]).": ".$filas[$i] ?> </li></ul> </h6><?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que fetchAll() devuelve un array numérico? Bien podría ser asociativo. Antes del for coloca **var_dump($resultadoDatos);** para que sepas cómo vienen. Por cierto, estás creando una lista dentro de un título para cada campo. Por favor agrega un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar la salida.

Comment: Hola, un var_dump de $ fila me arroja los siguientes resultados:

 'nombre' => string 'Juan' (length=4)
  0 => string 'Juan' (length=4)
  'apellidos' => string 'Galvines' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Galvines' (length=8)
  'dni' => string '48735526D' (length=9)
  2 => string '48735526D' (length=9)
  'direccion' => string 'Calle Amargura, 4 Trabanca' (length=26)
  3 => string 'Calle Amargura, 4 Trabanca' (length=26)
  'telefono' => string '956996894' (length=9)
  4 => string '956996894' (length=9)
Quiero obtener los campos nombre, apellidos, ...

Comment: pues tu mismo lo has escrito, el indice es el nombre del campo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo con ciclo, no se puede con for, porque las claves no son numéricas, en todo caso, recorre cada fila por clave y valor (foreach):

```
function comprobarDatos($pdo) {
    $sql = 'SELECT nombre, apellidos, dni, direccion, telefono from usuarios where login=:login';

    $gsent = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $login = [$_SESSION['login']];
    $gsent->execute($login);

    $resultadoDatos = $gsent->fetchAll();
    foreach($resultadoDatos as $filas){
        // Inicia con el título y abriendo la lista
        echo "<h6>Usuario</h6>\n<ul>";
        // Recorre el array por clave y valor
        // Funciona también para claves numéricas
        foreach($filas as $clave => $valor) {
            // Cada elemento de la lista
            echo "<li>$clave: $valor</li>\n";
        }
        // Cierra la lista
        echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

Semánticamente no es correcto poner toda la lista dentro de un título, son cosas completamente diferentes, por eso las separé y, adicionalmente, tal vez sea conveniente mostrar los nombres de campo con la primera letra en mayúscula usando la función ucfirst().